# My "Ficus religiosa" sapling stopped growing. How to make it grow again?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, indoors, tree-care, ficus

I received this sapling more than 14 months back (April 2019). I had been growing this indoors in the same pot I received it until recently when I switched to a bigger pot in the picture below.
[image]
I was able to see the sapling turn new leaves every week until it stopped recently. I was keeping this by the side of the window and I noticed that the tip turned brown (likely due to the recent increase in temperature in the recent days) after which it stopped turning new leaves. Any suggestions on how to make it grow? I am moving this to a new location with less direct sunlight. Does cutting the the top/tip help it to grow?
[image]

Comment: Good question and illustrations; if could include overall height, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount & frequency, average recent day temperature, average recent night temperature, size of container, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and to browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

The plant probably needs time to adjust to its new larger container, before it will thrive and grow new leaves again. Maybe the roots were damaged during the transplantation, or it is cooping with the heat. Try to keep it in the same conditions as the past (successful) 14 months, when it was doing well. Same watering regime and light intensity.

These (and related) Figs form new leaves in the pointy tip, and when the new leaves come and unfold the tip gets brown and dry and falls off. I am not sure if this is the case with your brown tip, now. I would leave the tip as it is, and wait for the plant to decide when it want to grow again. If the tip is damaged and will not form new leaves, the plant will get rid of it by itself and will find a new place to grow (between leaf and stem).

I have a rubber fig myself, which has very much the same tip and growth strategy. I have noticed that the intervals between new leaf growth may vary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, benn. I was happy to see the plant growing after i transplanted to the new container and new location near the window (not that far from it previously location). Since it stopped suddenly, it made me think that it was due to excessive heat. Hopefully, this is just a phase in the process and it will start growing again.